# Obtaining Instapaper OAuth access token from Delphi

Tags: delphi, instapaper

I am having trouble obtaining an access token from the Instapaper api using Overbyte's ICS suite.  The odd thing is that I am able to get an access token using Indy.  I am using Delphi XE2 and ICS version 7.

For debugging purposes, I am using fixed strings for post data and authorization headers.  Since the Indy code works, the problem does not seem to be signature related.

I would like to get this working with ICS ... any ideas on why the code does not work?  I'm getting an invalid signature error (signature does not match expected value).  The authorization header and post body should be identical to what I'm sending with Indy, so sounds like it has something to do with the ICS request.

Here is the Indy code that works (I get oauth_token and oauth_token_secret back)

```
var
  Params: TStringList;
  AuthHeader: STring;
  idHTTP: TIDHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin 
  idHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(Self);
  SslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  idHTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
  idHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];   
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  Params.Add('x_auth_mode=client_auth');
  Params.Add('x_auth_password=mypassword');
  Params.Add('x_auth_username=myusername%40gmail.com');
  idHTTP.Request.Host := 'https://www.instapaper.com';
  AuthHeader := 'Authorization: ' + 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="myconsumerkey", oauth_nonce="BAFWMTGFXNXSTNKUENBC", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="sEfq8gHlHYfrmLy5u0kKBgTYmVA%3D", oauth_timestamp="1369669197", oauth_version="1.0"';
  idHTTP.request.CustomHeaders.Add(AuthHeader);
  Response := idHTTP.Post('https://www.instapaper.com/api/1/oauth/access_token', Params);
end;
```

Here is the ICS code that fails (invalid signature):

```
var
  PostData: AnsiString;
begin
  PostData := 'x_auth_mode=client_auth&x_auth_password=mypassword&x_auth_username=myusername%40gmail.com';
  SSLHTTPClient := TSslHttpCli.Create(nil);
  With SSLHTTPClient do
  begin
    RcvdStream         := TMemoryStream.Create;
    SendStream         := TMemoryStream.Create;
    SendStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    SendStream.Write(PostData[1], Length(PostData));
    SendStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    URL                := 'https://www.instapaper.com/api/1/oauth/access_token';
    OnRequestDone      := SSLHTTPClientRequestDone;
    OnBeforeHeaderSend := HTTPClientBeforeHeaderSend;    // add the authorization header
    SslContext := TSslContext.Create(SSLHTTPClient);
    PostAsync;
  end;
end;

procedure TInstapaperOAuth.HTTPClientBeforeHeaderSend(Sender: TObject; const Method: string; Headers: TStrings);
var
  Header: String;
begin
  Header := 'Authorization: ' + 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="myconsumerkey", oauth_nonce="BAFWMTGFXNXSTNKUENBC", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="sEfq8gHlHYfrmLy5u0kKBgTYmVA%3D", oauth_timestamp="1369669197", oauth_version="1.0"';
  Headers.Add(Header);
end;
```

Comment: I got the ICS request to work by modifying the Host header.  In ICS, the Host header includes a port number, the Indy request header does not.  So changing the host header from "Host: www.instapaper.com:443" to "Host: www.instapaper.com", seems to fix the invalid signature error.  Does that sound right ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm accepting the above comment as the answer to this question.  So to work around this problem, update HTTPClientBeforeHeaderSend to replace the Host record along with adding the oauth header:

```
procedure TInstapaperOAuth.HTTPClientBeforeHeaderSend(Sender: TObject; const Method: string; Headers: TStrings);
var
  Header: String;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Header := 'Authorization: ' + 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="myconsumerkey", oauth_nonce="BAFWMTGFXNXSTNKUENBC", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="sEfq8gHlHYfrmLy5u0kKBgTYmVA%3D", oauth_timestamp="1369669197", oauth_version="1.0"';
  Headers.Add(Header);

  //=======================================
  //  find the host record and replace it
  //=======================================
  for I := 0 to Headers.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if pos('Host:',Headers.Strings[I]) > 0 then
    begin
      Headers.Strings[I] := 'Host: www.instapaper.com';
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```